# Uploadify Script data does not return unicoded characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

in my application i upload files using uploadify. everythings works perfect with standart unicode a-z 0-9.

here is a sample.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(window).load(
                   function () {
                       $('#fileuploaderImage').fileUpload({
                           uploader: '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                           script: '@Url.Action("Test", "Test")',
                           scriptData: { ProjectName: @Model.ProjectName },
                           cancelImg: '/Images/cancel.png',
                           auto: true,
                           multi: false,
                           folder: '/uploads',
                           fileDesc: 'Image',
                           sizeLimit: '200000000',
                           fileExt: '*.png;',
                           'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                               $("#img-path").val(response);
                           }
                       });

                   }
                  );    
    </script>
```

So u see that i pass ProjectName property to my controller by using ScriptData, it will work. but if ProjectName is like "MMMÅØÆÅÅØÆ" property in controller will only return "MMM" and rest of the string disapear. Anyone had same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is encoding issue.

Use like this:

```
scriptData: { ProjectName: encodeURIComponent('@Model.ProjectName') },
```

This should fix you issue.

Comment: Tryed that, but with no success

Comment: okay nowits return MMM&564;&564;&564;&564; i asume &564; is encoded value for Æ for example? are there anyway to decode it on server side? or do i have to do string.replace?

Comment: @Timsen You can use `String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);` to decode string on server side.

Comment: doesnt work.. Decoded string return same : l&#230;&#248;&#229;

Comment: Solution was to user: Server.HtmlDecode(string); but u was close